# Android SDK won't load file as bitmap... how do I fix this?

Tags: java, android, file, bitmap, png

I have been reading the book called "Beginning Android Games" by Mario Zechner and he has an example that is linked here in Google code.

http://code.google.com/p/beginning-android-games/source/browse/trunk/ch04-android-basics/src/com/badlogic/androidgames/BitmapTest.java

When I ran this it just shutdown on me and said Main Activity has shutdown unexpectedly.

When I ran the hello world the SDK worked just fine, but I am not sure where to start.

Android 2.2 API Level 8 is the Device I have selected since that's what my phone has.

Here is the code I was trying to run.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    class RenderView extends View {
        Bitmap bob565;
        Bitmap bob4444;
        Rect dst = new Rect();

        public RenderView(Context context) {
            super(context);

            try {
                AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
                InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("helmet.png");
                bob565 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                inputStream.close();
                Log.d("BitmapText",
                        "bobrgb888.png format: " + bob565.getConfig());

                inputStream = assetManager.open("helmet.png");
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444;
                bob4444 = BitmapFactory
                        .decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
                inputStream.close();
                Log.d("BitmapText",
                        "bobargb8888.png format: " + bob4444.getConfig());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // silently ignored, bad coder monkey, baaad!
            } finally {
                // we should really close our input streams here.
            }
        }

        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            dst.set(50, 50, 350, 350);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bob565, null, dst, null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bob4444, 100, 100, null);
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(new RenderView(this));
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you seeing in your log?  Do you have an idea as to which command is causing the crash?

Comment: @bdares I don't know how to access the log...

Comment: It won't go to stdout I believe, but if you're using Eclipse there will be a tab in your debug perspective that spits out all the log messages.

Comment: @bdares I use NetBeans, is there a way I can do it with NetBeans?

Comment: Zeveso, under the android-sdk dir on your machine open the tools folder and then DDMS from there. It will let you look at the log messages.

Comment: @slayton this did not work, when I opened the ddms.bat it opend a CMD prompt for a split second and then closed...

Comment: @Zeveso you need to run ddms from the command prompt.

Comment: @slayton that would help wouldn't it? XD  thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AssetManager way did not work. So I tried the following method and this did work for me.

```
public Bitmap getImage(String location) {
        InputStream is = RenderView.class.getResourceAsStream(location);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
}
```

RenderView is just the current class... so if your writing this code under Main.java you would write:

```
Main.class.getResourcesAsStream();
```

location is just the path to the file. For example if you have  a image called ball.jpg under images folder you would just write:

```
String location = "images/ball.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh dear, please put `helmet.png` image into project `assets` directory....

This code is totally running fine! The only problem can exist is that `helmet.png not found`

Comment: this did not solve my problem, I am still having the same issue. Although I am sure that issue would have come up later so thanks...

Comment: wow, then show the log? Use `ddms.bat` in `/tools/` directory

Comment: finally started to figure out how to use Dalvik Debug and got the error java.lang.NullPointerException.... I even have it in the folder assets that you told me to use... was wondering if when I use assetManger.open(fileName); if the fileName should include a directory... if so how should it be done?